# Why is live-build failing to find this package?

Tags: 12.04, live-cd, live-usb

I am trying to use live-build to create a remix of ubuntu 12.04. My goal is a bootable liveusb that can install the base ubuntu system plus my custom packages. I am using live-build with the following config options:

```
 lb config --mode ubuntu --distribution precise --hostname livecd --username livecduser --archive-areas "main contrib" --binary-images iso-hybrid --architecture amd64 --debian-installer live
```

For some reason it fails with the following error:

```
Building dependency tree... Done
E: Unable to locate package console-common
P: Begin unmounting filesystems...
```

Strangely:

```
apt-cache search console-common
console-common - basic infrastructure for text console configuration
```

Anyone have thoughts or guidance on why this is failing?

Answer (score 0):

You've only enabled the `main` and `contrib` areas, but the `console-common` package is provided by the Universe repository. Try `--archive-areas "main universe contrib"` instead.

```
$ apt-cache policy console-common
console-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.7.85
  Version table:
     0.7.85 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: I just tried it again. I deleted the entire folder, created a new one and ran lb config with archive-areas "main universe contrib", then sudo lb build and got the same thing. I did the same procedure including multiverse (why not?) and got the same result. Any other thoughts? Could one of my other settings be screwing it up somehow?

Comment: What mirror are you using? Can you add more details (output) to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same issue as you and the most that I find is to put directly the .deb downloading in ubuntu in the packages.chroot directory (if you have the 3.0 version) and if you need an other package for dependances do the same.

Comment: The answer is not clear.